zsh auto complete not completing for macOS 'defaults' command
I have enabled zsh-completions using zinit and however when attempting to use completions with the 'defaults' command such as defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /path/to/ it seems to fail to utilise the autocomplete feature when filling in the path. It works fine for all the other arguments however it is unable to autocomplete for the path.
This issue only seems to localised to this specific command as it works fine with other macOS specific commands such as swift and open. I was wondering whether I might have set up zsh-completions incorrectly or whether this is an issue others may have encountered or is this expected behavior.
I install zsh-completions like so:
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions

I also have the following zstyles:
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
zstyle ':completion:*' menu no
zstyle ':completion:*' list-suffixes
zstyle ':completion:*' expand prefix suffix

I have tried reinstalling completions if I had a bad install however I am still able to reproduce this issue.
Please let me know if more infomation is needed to help diagnose this issue.

I don't see how you have setup the completions for defaults. zsh right out the box most likely does not support this (why should it?). You could have a look here, and perhaps here, but I don't know whether they do defaults.

Thank you, I've looked at the mac-zsh-completions github repo and followed the installation steps but that doesn't include the completion for defaults either. I've also got the zsh-users/zsh-completions I'm just using zinit for faster loading. It does seem like there isn't an option to add completion for defaults which is annoying but it's not very often that I really use the defaults command

Well, as in general with open source stuff, if nobody has volunteered yet to write it, it's not available. Perhaps you could take the burden and develop such a completion package, and then upload it at github?
